# When I run my old android project I get a error message from the build.gradle

Tags: android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin

When I run my old android project I get a  error message:

"WARNING: Configuration 'compile' is obsolete and has been replaced with 'implementation' and 'api'.
It will be removed at the end of 2018. For more information see: http://d.android.com/r/tools/update-dependency-configurations.html
Affected Modules: app"

I tried to use the google()in allprojects but get the same error message.

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 27

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.android.firebaseupload"
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 27
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    allprojects {
        repositories {
            jcenter()
            maven {
                url 'https://maven.google.com'
            }
        }
    }

        dependencies {

            implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
            androidTestImplementation('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
                exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
            })


            implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'
            implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.0.+'
            implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-storage:17.0.0'
            implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:17.0.0'
            implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:17.0.0'
            implementation 'com.github.gcacace:signature-pad:1.2.1'
            implementation 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.0'
            implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:3.7.0'
            implementation 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:27.0.0'
            implementation 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:27.0.0'
            implementation 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-database:0.4.0'
            implementation 'com.android.support:design:27.0.0'
            implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:27.0.0'
            implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-plus:17.0.0'
            testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
        }





}
```

apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'

"WARNING: Configuration 'compile' is obsolete and has been replaced with 'implementation' and 'api'.
It will be removed at the end of 2018. For more information see: http://d.android.com/r/tools/update-dependency-configurations.html
Affected Modules: app"

Comment: try invalidate cache

Comment: Add  `google()` in the `repositories`  then `clean` your project and  `Rebuild`. After that, if not run then `try invalidate cache` that @Ticherhaz said.

Hope it will work. If not then please let us know.

Comment: It is just a warning, everything will be okay even if does exist.

Answer (score 0):

It looks that the problem is from:

```
implementation 'com.github.gcacace:signature-pad:1.2.1'
```

Check out this link

[https://github.com/gcacace/android-signaturepad/blob/master/SignaturePad-Example/build.gradle][1]

it looks that the developer haven't updated his code since a while so the solution in your case is to :

1- Download https://github.com/gcacace/android-signaturepad as zip

2- Open its Gradle files in app modules and replace compile with implementation

3- After making sure that there's no Compile keyword any more, go to Android project in Android studio Click file->New->Import Module->select the folder where you extracted the project and edited it and that's it

- make sure that all of your dependencies are using the latest version

Answer (score 0):

try add

```
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

in second line of your gradle file